# Python single function with and without parameters

Tags: python, pandas

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjqeq.png)

[My Partial Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd7Ek.png)

What I have to do if I want to run the function with the parameters and without the parameters at the same time as asked in the question?

CODE :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def range_series(x,y):
  if not x:
    x=1
  if not y:
    y=10
  d = np.array([])
  d = np.arange(x,y)
  s = pd.Series(d)
  print(s)
  print(type(s))
```

range_series(5,10)

Comment: Please, add the code directly, without linking to external images

Comment: Same for the quoted question, include the text in the question so that it can be easily read and searched.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need default parameters in the function header.

For example:

```py
def my_func(x=2, y=3)
  print(x+y)
```

This function assigns the value 2 to x and 3 to y when these parameters are not specified.

Hence:

```py
my_func()
> 5
my_func(5, 10)
> 15
```